# SelectMany and DefaultIfEmpty inside SelectMany wrong working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I wanna get all childs for requested items ordered by desc which has linked query. When Im trying use SelectMany with DefaultIfEmpty inside another SelectMany:

```
DbSet<MyRecord<long>>().FromSql(select * from unnest({0}), object[] { NpgsqlParameter<MyRecord<long>[]> })
.SelectMany(pk => dataContext.TestItems
    .Where(item => pk.Item == item.ParentId)
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: entity => dataContext.TestQueries
            .Where(a => a.QueryId == entity.EntityId)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        resultSelector: (left, right) => new JoinResult<TestItem, TestQuery>{ 
            Left = left, 
            Right = right 
        }
    )
    .OrderByDescending(result => result.Right.ObjectId)
    .Select(result => result.Left))
```

With entities

```
class MyRecord<T>
{
    public T Item {get;set;}
}
class JoinResult<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Left { get; set; }
    public T2 Right { get; set; }
}
class  TestItem
{
    public int EntityId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;} // link to TestItem.EntityId
}
class  TestQuery
{
    public int QueryId {get;set;}
}
```

I get sql query:

```
SELECT t0.EntityId, t0.Name, t0.ParentId
FROM (
    select * from unnest(ARRAY[101,102])
) AS e
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT c.EntityId, c.Name, c.ParentId
    FROM items AS c
    JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT s.QueryId
        FROM queries AS q
        WHERE q.QueryId = c.EntityId
    ) AS t ON TRUE
    WHERE e.unnest = c.ParentId
    ORDER BY t.QueryId DESC
) AS t0 ON TRUE
```

But I expect LEFT JOIN inside CROSS JOIN. How can I stop transform query on first SelectMany and get smh:

```
SELECT t0.EntityId, t0.Name, t0.ParentId
FROM (
    select * from unnest(ARRAY[101,102])
) AS e
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT c.EntityId, c.Name, c.ParentId
    FROM items AS c
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT s.QueryId
        FROM queries AS q
        WHERE q.QueryId = c.EntityId
    ) AS t ON TRUE
    WHERE e.unnest = c.ParentId
    ORDER BY t.QueryId DESC
) AS t0 ON TRUE
```

I think DefaultIfEmpty set SelectMany as LEFT JOIN but translation must be on inner extension. How can I change query to get expected sql on this signature?

Im try use GroupJoin but this feature broken lot of existing logic so I think is no accessiable.
This behaviour repeated in .net 6 and 8 for all our builds

**Upd**:

My bad. I thought so difficult and solution is very easy:

```cs
DbSet<MyRecord<long>>().FromSql(select * from unnest({0}), object[] { NpgsqlParameter<MyRecord<long>[]> })
.SelectMany(pk => dataContext.TestItems
    .Where(item => pk.Item == item.ParentId))
.SelectMany(entity => dataContext.TestQueries.Where(a => a.QueryId == entity.EntityId)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        (left, right) => new JoinResult<TestItem, TestQuery>{Left = left, 
            Right = right })
    .OrderByDescending(result => result.Right.ObjectId)
    .Select(result => result.Left)
```

I dont thought about outer selectMany result and lost joined entities. Fixed query is work correctly.
But DefaultIfEmpty behaviour not work correctly yet I think. Its must change inner subquery and save outer. Well it is no matter now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't quite syntactically correct, I've had to assume what you intended.

Your primary issue is that you are ordering the outer query when you only want to order the inner children.

Also you don't need an entity to create a raw query of a single column. You can use `context.Database.SqlQuery` instead.

```cs
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<long>($"select * from unnest({ new NpgsqlParameter("@items", listHere) })")
    .SelectMany(pk => dataContext.TestItems
        .Where(item => pk == item.ParentId)
        .SelectMany(
            collectionSelector: entity => dataContext.TestQueries
                .Where(a => a.QueryId == entity.EntityId)
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.ObjectId)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(),
            resultSelector: (left, right) => new JoinResult<TestItem, TestQuery>
            { 
                Left = left, 
                Right = right 
            }
        )
        .Select(result => result.Left)
    )
```

I'm not clear why you have this whole inner `SelectMany` anyway. It seems you should just select the inner result into a list, something like:

```cs
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<long>($"select * from unnest({ new NpgsqlParameter("@items", listHere) })")
    .SelectMany(pk => dataContext.TestItems
        .Where(item => pk == item.ParentId)
        .Select(item => new JoinResult<TestItem, TestQuery>
            { 
                Left = item,
                Right = dataContext.TestQueries
                    .Where(a => a.QueryId == entity.EntityId)
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.ObjectId)
                    .ToList(),
            }
        )
    )
```

Comment: Using .Include is not correct because TestItems has not link to TestQueries. They linked only by polymorph link by value

Comment: OK see new edit

Comment: But now we can`t get child for entities. I need to get all childs for some entities witch have polymorph link to query item. In your code we will get entities with linked query item  but need exactly childs

Comment: and left will be a long value not TestItem

Comment: Sorry you're right I missed off some edits to take it back to what you had.

Comment: This code translate to 
```SQL 
SELECT t1."Id", t1."Name", t1."Parent"
FROM (
    select * from unnest(new ARRAY[1,2,3])
) AS t
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT t0."Id", t0."Name", t0."Parent"
    FROM "TestEntities" AS t0
    INNER JOIN "TestQueries" AS t2 ON t0."Id" = t2."Id"
    WHERE t."Value" = t0."Parent"::bigint OR (t."Value" IS NULL AND t0."Parent" IS NULL)
) AS t1 ON TRUE
```

Comment: Anyway first query is more correct by logic but I think problem in transform linq to sql cause DefaultIfEmpty must translate inner selectMany to leftJoin if using inside. But in reality inner DefaultIfEmpty  translate outer selectMany

Comment: selectMany needed because entity and query have one-to-many polymorphic link, So joinResult must be JoinResult<TestItem, ienumerable<TestQuery>> and reification in query is not working. So we must use selectMany